# Unable to debug the kernel driver using Serial cable

Tags: windows, debugging, serial-port, kernel, windbg

I am new to driver stuff. I have tried to debug the kernel driver using serial COM port without success. Could someone show me proper direction how to fix the problem?

I am seeing the following messages on kd console.

ERROR: DavReadRegistryValues/RegQueryValueExW(4). WStatus = 127
ERROR: DavReadRegistryValues/RegQueryValueExW(5). WStatus = 127
ERROR: DavReadRegistryValues/RegQueryValueExW(6). WStatus = 127

At this time, I pressed Ctl^D and kd console and I am seeing
READ: Timeout.
READ: Wait for type 7 packet
READ: Timeout.
READ: Wait for type 7 packet
READ: Timeout.

EDIT: The problem is fixed with WinDbg. I changed the baud rate to 115200 and inserted break (Ctr ^ Break) before Target system completely boots up. I am able to debug the code now. If I insert break after the target system completely boots up then I am unable to debug. I don't know exact reason for it but Happy with current situation.

`Here are the things I have done`

```
1) Prepared Target system for debug mode by editing the boot.ini file. Added     “/debugport=com1 /baudrate=57600”  to boot.ini

2) On Host system, started kd.exe and seeing the following output

C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows>kd.exe -k com:port=1,baud=57600
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger  Version 6.6.0007.5
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Opened \\.\com1
Waiting to reconnect...

3) Rebooted Target system, system boots slowly than normal boot and I am seeing some     messages <<below>> on Host system console

4) At this time, If I press Ctl-C on KD console then Target system freezes (hangs)         and proceeds if I enter "g" at kd prompt.  This means that Target system     is going to debug mode

5) However After some time I am seeing the following message on the host machine console

ERROR: DavReadRegistryValues/RegQueryValueExW(4). WStatus = 127  
ERROR: DavReadRegistryValues/RegQueryValueExW(5). WStatus = 127  
ERROR: DavReadRegistryValues/RegQueryValueExW(6). WStatus = 127  

After the above message there are no messages appearing on kd console.

I searched internet for "ERROR: DavReadRegistryValues/RegQueryValueExW(6). WStatus =     127" but didn't get proper reason for it.

I pressed Ctl^D and kd console and I am seeing 
READ: Timeout.  
READ: Wait for type 7 packet  
READ: Timeout.  
READ: Wait for type 7 packet  
READ: Timeout.  

I have tried above steps with following options ..but no luck

I disabled firewall & antivirus software on both Host and Target systems. 
I unplugged and re-plugged serial cable connection between each trail
I have logged-in with Domain account local account with Admin rights 


Can someone show some light on how to proceed? Both systems are running on XP 32bit     SP3 OS.
```

Thanks
King

Comment: Hello kingas did you fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you have a good serial connection?

The cable must be a null modem cable - you should verify this using a terminal program (without kernel debugging enabled on the target).  Run the program (HyperTerminal or whatever) on both the target and the host machines (remember, like I said before kernel debugging over that port must not be enabled on the target or the port can't be opened).

You can find some links to free terminal programs (I don't think Microsoft provides HyperTerminal anymore since Vista) here: http://www.lvr.com/serport.htm#software

Type some characters on one machine, and make sure they show up on the other side.  Do the same on the other machine.

If you can't do this, then there's no serial connection and you'll have to get a null modem cable or adapter.  There's no point in trying to get KD to work over that connection until you can do this.

Also, remember that the COM port used by kernel debugging on the target must be a standard 8250 family UART (usually a 16550 or better nowadays, and usually baked into the motherboard chipset). It can't be a USB serial port connector (although that kind will work fine on the host side, since on the host kd.exe is a regular Win32 program).

Edit:

---

If it's not a serial connection problem, the problem might be that your target doesn't support configuration using `boot.ini`.  Since Vista, boot parameters have been specified using the "Boot Configuration Database" (BCD) which is manipulated with a program like `bcdedit.exe`. Unfortunately, configuring a system using BCDedit is much more complicated than just editing a simple text file like `boot.ini`.

You should read the debugger helpfile section "Configuring Software on the Target Computer"; in particular the "Using Boot Parameters" part.  there are details there on how bcdedit can be used to enable debugging on Vista and later systems.

Comment: Thanks for quick info. I disabled kernel debugging mode on Target system and verified that RS232 serial cable is good by using HyperTerminal program. I am able to send the characters from Host to Target system and VV. Both systems are running with Windows XP 32bit SP3 OS. COM ports are part on Mother board on both systems. I don't know exactly about UART spec..I will try get some info. Are there any other suggestion which I can try? Thanks King

Comment: If you're not using a USB to serial port device then the COM port hardware should be fine - you don't need to determine the actual UART part number.  I was just trying to reinforce that it can't be  a USB serial ort on the target.

Comment: Sorry - I missed the line about both systems running WinXP SP3 32-bit. On re-reading I don't see the "/debug" boot.ini option mentioned - is that on the boot.ini entry?

Comment: I have added “/debugport=com1 /baudrate=57600”  to boot.ini file on Target system. Do I need to add /debug option ?

Comment: Yes, I am using win XP systems not Vista.

Comment: I've never tried it without (except maybe by accident). I'm not at a machine where I can verify, but I'm pretty sure it's necessary and is not implied by having '/debugport'.

Comment: Michael, Thanks for your help. Some how I am able to make debug working using winDbg. I don't know exactly why it didn't work using kd. Presently I am  continuing with WinDbg.

Comment: @kingas - that's very strange.  As far as I know, WinDbg and kd use the same debugging engine DLL library, which is what should be responsible for the communications to the target (though it's possible that I don't know what I'm talking about).  However, WinDbg and kd have exactly the same fundamental capabilities, so you're not losing anything (in fact the command window in WinDbg is essentially a kd console).

Answer (score 0):

The other thing you can test to see if debugging is working on the target is to invoke kd -kl *on the target* - if it tells you debugging isn't enabled, you haven't set up boot.ini correctly.