# Win7's debug mode not work on VirtualBox's guest machine

Tags: serial-port, kernel, virtualbox, windbg, remote-debugging

I install Win7 at my virtualbox, setup the guest end a standard "bcdedit"s. (debugtype=serial, port=1, baudrate=115200 /debug=on)

following steps took:

1. In the host end, I alloc a virtual serial port to the guest system
2. set the it with named-pipe "\.\pipe\debug".
3. I start Windbg to connect "\.\pipe\debug", I get "Could not open the pipe Win32 error 0n2"
4. After I power on the guest machine, I reopen Windbg, it works fine, but just saying "Opend \.\pipe\debug Waiting to reconnect...", It seems that no debugging data communicated with Guest Machine.
5. I try "bcdedit /bootdebug on",  and reboot the machine. this time I see several output by Windbg during booting.

> BD: Boot Debugger Initialized Connected to Windows Boot Debugger 7601
>   x64 target at (Sat Mar 17 17:28:46.559 2018 (UTC + 8:00)), ptr64 TRUE
>   Kernel Debugger connection established.
>   ************* Path validation summary ************** Response                         Time (ms)     Location Deferred
>   srv*C:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols Symbol
>   search path is:
>   srv*C:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols Executable
>   search path is:  ReadVirtual() failed in GetXStateConfiguration()
>   first read attempt (error == 997. Windows Boot Debugger Kernel Version
>   7601 UP Free x64 Machine Name: Primary image base =
>   0x00000000`0052d000 Loaded module list = 0x00000000`005df9e0 System
>   Uptime: not available **Shutdown occurred at (Sat Mar 17 17:28:53.382
>   2018 (UTC + 8:00))...unloading all symbol tables**.

It proves "\.\pipe\debug" is OK to transfer output of Guest VM's COM1.

6. When entering to login console, I see such message, and previous outputs turn to gray:

> ************* Path validation summary ************** Response                         Time (ms)     Location Deferred
>   srv*C:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols Waiting to
>   reconnect...

7. I login and check the Device Manager, I can't find device COM1. but if I turn off /debug, I can.(Indeed, I used putty to check Guest'COM1 with Host's rawfile, I found it worked too, with the input of putty written to Host's file)
8. I tried many times with different COMs and baudrate, always got same outputs.
9. I tried a similar VMware Station, and got the same result.
10. Problem disappeared after I changed a Host machine and redid above steps.(:

Questions:

1. WHY can't I see the COM1 device with /debug on In the guest machine?
2. Does the Baudrate matters? (mismatch among Host's windbg setting, Guest's Device setting and Guest's debug setting), I tried to "Cycle BaudRate "In Windbg, it said Net COM port baud is ignored.
3. How to diagnose the problem?

**_EDIT：**

I found a similar post [stuck on "reconnecting"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30049300/windbg-first-connect-then-stuck-on-debuggee-not-connected-message-during-kern?rq=1)
and this issue [My Kernel Debugger Won’t Connect](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ntdebugging/2011/12/29/my-kernel-debugger-wont-connect/) which refered there was a hot key "Ctrl+Alt+D" to show details of Windbg's I/O instead of a black-box. And it's normal and reasonable that COM1 disappear when "/debug=on" as the post said.

I could see the efforts windbg payed to sync the guest. After I pressed "ctrl+break", I saw windbg said "Send Sync", and still stuck... And, I would going to power off the guest by pressing "Host+Q". Miracle took place. Windbg came to alive and succeeded to break in.

I tried several times, with no failure. Now I can work happily... But WHY???

when I press "Ctrl+break", the windbg says

> Send sync break
>
> Send Break in ...

and stuck, and target machine is paused too. And I press "Host+Q" the "Esc" then it works.

Answer (score 0):

install vbox in physical machine  (the physical machine is **Host** henceforth)
install os inside vbox    ( the os inside vbox is **Target** henceforth)
reboot Target and see if things go well a few times
open a elevated command prompt inside Target

since you have not created a Debug BootEntry create one first

```
run bcdedit /copy /? for syntax 
to copy current bootentry to a new one you will be using 
bcddedit /copy {current} /d "MyPipeDream" 
{current} is alias for the current boot entry ID a GUID
MyPipeDream is a descriptive string 
if you reboot now you should get two boot entries to choose from
```

[image]

choose the new bootentry to boot with so that you can operate with **{current}** well known ID instead of copy pasting or mistyping long unintuitive guids

assuming you booted MyPipeDream

you can check and enable debugging on the current id with 
**bcdedit /debug {current} on**

you should reboot again to MyPipeDream which would be debug enabled now as in screen shots below

[image]

[image]

but before rebooting set the Serial Interface in vbox settings

also uncheck the connect to existing so that vbox creates the pipe 
instead of trying to connect to an existing pipe

all setting on target are over now

[image]

on the host create a bat file with contents below and execute it 
notice the pipename it is pipedream exactly matching the name we gave in vbox settings and not MyDreamPipe which is the ID descriptive string

```
start windbg -k com:port=\\.\pipe\pipedream,baud=115200,pipe,reconnect,resets=0
```

windbg should open up and say witing to reconnect

press **ctrl+break a few times in the HOST WINDBG** and vbox should connect to windbg  or **press ctrl+print screen in the TARGET**

please see if you require Function keys (some wireless keyboards like logitech
needs **ctrl+fn+pause / break** key combos instead of plain ctrl+break

else open the Debug menu and select the Break in UI

Comment: Indeed, my setup is just like what you advise, /copy, set it debug on, alloc a serial port, reboot and choose the new boot entry. I understand every step and every option above under the hood. Howerver It doesn't work, just saying "Debuggee not connected". I check that the virtual serial port is reachable to host's pipe. Just no debugging protocols exchange even if guest os set debug on.

Comment: scrap it and redo maybe it works just like that on vpc , vbox , qemu , vmware and whatnot  /debug on is the only command that is required and if you can use a os > win 8.1 in target you can use net debugging and that also works without hitch afaik