# WinDBG kernel debugging starts only sometimes

Tags: windows, debugging, kernel, windbg

For me, kernel debugging doesn't start on each boot. On some 70% boots, WinDBG reports connection, but then it's quickly lost and WinDBG shows `Debuggee not connected`.

Various observations:

1. Target is Windows 11 22H2
2. I use WinDBG `10.0.22621.755` on both machines.
3. I set up kernel debugging using `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\kdnet.exe" 192.168.2.1 50000`
4. On target machine, I use suggested `windbg -k net:port=50000,key=...` command to start WinDBG
5. I boot/shutdown target computer many times, without changing anything, until it finally connects reliably
6. WinDBG always reacts to target computer booting by printing messages, but it often disconnects almost immediately.
7. If debugger is still connected by the time of Windows login screen, the connection is never lost until I reboot debugged computer
8. Using `WinDBG > Debug > Kernel connection > Cycle initial break` doesn't really help: when connection fails, WinDBG reports successful connection but doesn't break and then shows `Debuggee not connected`.
9. When debugger fails to connect, target does NOT show `Test Mode` in the bottom right corner of desktop.
10. ... but I can still see `This device has been reserved for use by Windows kernel debugger` in Device Manager on my network card.
11. ... and I sometimes have and sometimes don't have `Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter` in device manager
12. Using `WinDBG > View > Verbose output` doesn't give any helpful messages to explain the disconnect.
13. Judging from `Debuggee not connected` in WinDBG following successful connect, I understand that WinDBG knows that it disconnected, but for some reason doesn't give any explanation.
14. Typical WinDBG output for failed connect:
    `Verbose mode ON. Will breakin at next boot. Connected to target 192.168.2.2 on port 50000 on local IP 192.168.2.1. You can get the target MAC address by running .kdtargetmac command.`
15. Both machines are connected to the same router, via cable.
16. According to SysInternals TCPView, only WinDBG listens on port 50000 on debugger machine.
17. Windows Event Log doesn't seem to have any relevant messages.
18. Enabled Windows Boot Logging and studied `C:\Windows\ntbtlog.txt` but didn't find anything interesting there.
19. As suggested in [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30049300) I tried to `WinDBG > Debug > Break` anyway, but it doesn't work when connection failed.

How do I make the connection reliable? Are there any advanced logs to read to figure why does target machine not start debugging (I make this conclusion from lack of `Test Mode` notice in bottom right corner of desktop)

**Update 1**
`kdnet` gives:

```
Network debugging is supported on the following NICs:
busparams=0.25.0, Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection, Plugged in.
```

Now that debugging starts sometimes, I understand that network card is compatible. The problem is that it only starts in some 15% cases or so.

> At which point have you configured the debugger to break (hypervisor, loader, boot)?

I used `WinDBG > Debug > Kernel connection > Cycle initial break`.
In previous attempts, I didn't configure any breaks and wanted to break manually (`WinDBG > Debug > Break`) which also didn't work.

> When Test Mode is not displayed, have you looked at the KD_DEBUGGER_ENABLED global kernel variable (you'll need kd and livekd from Sysinternals on your target)?

```
(WinDBG) ? dwo(nt!KdDebuggerEnabled)
Evaluate expression: 1 = 00000000`00000001
```

> Could you add the full output of bcdedit /enum all from the target machine to your post?

```
Firmware Boot Manager
---------------------
identifier              {fwbootmgr}
timeout                 0

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {aec6b6dd-bb3f-11ed-b0ad-d89d67cb10b5}
displayorder            {current}
                        {d073bfac-c76b-11ed-b0db-843a4b6e6260}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 3

Firmware Application (101fffff)
-------------------------------
identifier              {01757582-bf6b-11ed-b0cb-806e6f6e6963}
device                  unknown
path                    \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
description             ubuntu

Firmware Application (101fffff)
-------------------------------
identifier              {04035df6-879f-11ed-b02a-806e6f6e6963}
device                  unknown
path                    \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
description             ubuntu

Firmware Application (101fffff)
-------------------------------
identifier              {18bd1575-766c-11ec-9f5b-806e6f6e6963}
description             Notebook Ethernet

Firmware Application (101fffff)
-------------------------------
identifier              {18bd1576-766c-11ec-9f5b-806e6f6e6963}
description             Notebook Upgrade Bay

Firmware Application (101fffff)
-------------------------------
identifier              {18bd1577-766c-11ec-9f5b-806e6f6e6963}
description             Notebook Hard Drive

Firmware Application (101fffff)
-------------------------------
identifier              {342f29a6-2a3d-11ed-af4a-806e6f6e6963}
description             Notebook Ethernet

Firmware Application (101fffff)
-------------------------------
identifier              {a0ec6830-4dfe-11ed-af97-806e6f6e6963}
device                  unknown
path                    \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
description             ubuntu

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {8da16dbd-bb62-11ed-b0bb-d89d67cb10b5}
device                  ramdisk=[E:]\Recovery\WindowsRE\Winre.wim,{8da16dbe-bb62-11ed-b0bb-d89d67cb10b5}
path                    \windows\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows Recovery Environment
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
displaymessage          Recovery
osdevice                ramdisk=[E:]\Recovery\WindowsRE\Winre.wim,{8da16dbe-bb62-11ed-b0bb-d89d67cb10b5}
systemroot              \windows
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
winpe                   Yes

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 11
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {8da16dbd-bb62-11ed-b0bb-d89d67cb10b5}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \WINDOWS
resumeobject            {aec6b6dd-bb3f-11ed-b0ad-d89d67cb10b5}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
bootlog                 Yes
debug                   Yes

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {d073bfac-c76b-11ed-b0db-843a4b6e6260}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.efi
description             Win11 + Hyper-V
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {8da16dbd-bb62-11ed-b0bb-d89d67cb10b5}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \WINDOWS
resumeobject            {aec6b6dd-bb3f-11ed-b0ad-d89d67cb10b5}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
hypervisorlaunchtype    Auto

Resume from Hibernate
---------------------
identifier              {aec6b6dd-bb3f-11ed-b0ad-d89d67cb10b5}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winresume.efi
description             Windows Resume Application
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {resumeloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {8da16dbd-bb62-11ed-b0bb-d89d67cb10b5}
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
filedevice              partition=C:
custom:21000026         partition=C:
filepath                \hiberfil.sys
bootmenupolicy          Standard
debugoptionenabled      Yes

Windows Memory Tester
---------------------
identifier              {memdiag}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\memtest.efi
description             Windows Memory Diagnostic
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
badmemoryaccess         Yes

EMS Settings
------------
identifier              {emssettings}
bootems                 No

Debugger Settings
-----------------
identifier              {dbgsettings}
busparams               0.25.0
key                     <snip>
debugtype               NET
hostip                  <snip>
port                    50000
dhcp                    Yes

RAM Defects
-----------
identifier              {badmemory}

Global Settings
---------------
identifier              {globalsettings}
inherit                 {dbgsettings}
                        {emssettings}
                        {badmemory}

Boot Loader Settings
--------------------
identifier              {bootloadersettings}
inherit                 {globalsettings}
                        {hypervisorsettings}

Hypervisor Settings
-------------------
identifier              {hypervisorsettings}
hypervisordebugtype     Serial
hypervisordebugport     1
hypervisorbaudrate      115200

Resume Loader Settings
----------------------
identifier              {resumeloadersettings}
inherit                 {globalsettings}

Device options
--------------
identifier              {8da16dbe-bb62-11ed-b0bb-d89d67cb10b5}
description             Windows Recovery
ramdisksdidevice        partition=E:
ramdisksdipath          \Recovery\WindowsRE\boot.sdi
```

Comment: does `kdnet` says that your NIC is supported (just by running `kdnet.exe` on your target without any command line)? Is it able to give you the `busparams` of your NIC? At which point have you configured the debugger to break (hypervisor, loader, boot)? When `Test Mode` is not displayed, have you looked at the `KD_DEBUGGER_ENABLED` global kernel variable (you'll need kd and livekd from Sysinternals on your target)? Could you add the full output of `bcdedit /enum all` from the target machine to your post?

Comment: Added an update to answer your questions. Please remember that once in a while, debugger connects. All I need to do is to reboot, check if successful, reboot again - until it connects.